# Access spaCy Masked Language Model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, language-model

As of v2.1, spaCy has a BERT-style language model (LM). It predicts word-vectors instead of words, so I am going to use "words" and "word vectors" interchangeably here.

I need to take a sentence with a word masked, and a list of words, and rank the words by how likely they are to appear in the masked slot. Currently I am using BERT for this (similar to [bert-syntax](https://github.com/yoavg/bert-syntax/blob/master/eval_bert.py#L14)). I would like to see if spaCy's performance on this task is acceptable. Between [this file](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/_ml.py) and [this one](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/cli/pretrain.py) I'm pretty sure it's possible to build something. However, it feels like reaching deeper into the internals of the library than I'd like.

Is there a straightforward way to interact with spaCy's masked language model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the disadvantage of the LMAO approximation. I actually hadn't realised this until it was pointed out to me by someone on the `/r/machinelearning` subreddit.

Because we're predicting a vector, we really only get to predict one point in the vector-space. This is really different from predicting a distribution over the words. Imagine we had a gap like `The __ of corn.` Let's say a good distribution of fillers for that would be `{kernel, ear, piece}`. The vectors for these words aren't especially close, as the `word2vec` algorithm is constructing a vector space based on all contexts of the words, and the words are only interchangeable in this context. In the vast majority of uses of `piece`, the word `ear` would be a really bad substitution.

If the likely fillers aren't close together in the vector-space, there will be no way for the LMAO model to return you an answer that corresponds to that set of words.

If you only need the 1-best answer, the algorithm in `spacy pretrain` has a good chance of giving it to you. But if you need the distribution, the approximation breaks down, and you should use something like `BERT`.